# Issue writing to json file in android

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying to write into a json file and it just doesnt work, I dont get any errors but nothing changes in the file.

here is the relevant section of my code

```
        try {
            //method1
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String s = "gjsanhfhj";
            String path = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "test.json";

            File file = new File(path);
            file.setWritable(true);

            gson.toJson(s,new FileWriter(file));

            //method2
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            outputStream = openFileOutput(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();

            //method3
            Writer output;
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(s);
            output.close();


            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried the 3 methods above, didnt work I couldnt find anything else

I tried this

```
public class PlayerData {
    private int gold;
    private int wins;
    private int losses;

    public PlayerData(){
        gold = 0;
        wins = 0;
        losses = 0;
    }


            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String path = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "test.json";
            File file = new File(path);
            file.setWritable(true);

            gson.toJson(new PlayerData(),new FileWriter(file));
```

didnt work

Comment: If it didn't work, it almost certainly threw an exception.  What exception did it throw?

Comment: there were no exception (that im aware of at least) not in the debugger/catch/logcat couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This worked for me.

```
private class myString {
    String str;
    public myString() {
        this.str = "Testing123...";
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
    myString s = new myString();
    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "Test.json");

    try {
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] arr = gson.toJson(s).getBytes();
        fileOutputStream.write(arr);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gson.toJson(Obj) is used to convert an object into a Json-String which is a key value pair. Gson.toJson() takes a java object as an argument, whereas, you are passing a STRING value which not right, I think. For example, an object of Employee class, can be converted into json as below.

```
class Employee {
int empId;
String name;
String department;
```

} `

Now, you can call

```
gson.toJson(new Employee(100, "abc", "xyz"), new FileWriter(file));
```

So, please check your requirement again.

Comment: One solution to your problem is, embed the String variable 's' in an object and then use gson.toJson(object). It should work then.

Comment: tried it, didnt work

Comment: Did you check if the file is getting created?

Comment: the file existed prior
I tired deleting it and re running the project, nothing happened no file was created still no exceptions

Comment: Pls check my edited answer above. It has the solution. It works.